# For a compound random variable $\Sigma^N_{i=1} X_i$. find $Cov(N, S)$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

For a compound random variable $\Sigma^N_{i=1} X_i$. find $Cov(N, S)$

I know $Cov(X,Y) = E[SN] - E[S]E[N]$ but i'm not sure how to find andy of these values.

Comment: Is $S$ the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $S$ is the sum:

$$\mbox{Cov}(N,S)=E[NS]-E[N]E[S].$$ Assuming $X_i$ are iid with finite expectation and $N$ is independent of $X_i$ with finite expectation,

$$E[NS]=E[E[NS|N]]=E[NE[S|N]]=E[N^2E[X_1]]=E[X_1]E[N^2]-E[S]E[N],$$

then by Wald's identity: $E[S]=E[N]E[X_1]$, so you get:

$$\mbox{Cov}(N,S)=E[X_1](E[N^2]-E[N]^2)=E[X_1]\mbox{Var}(N).$$

Comment: I think you have a mistake: $E[NS]=E[E[NS]|N]]$ should be $E[NS]=E[E[NS|N]]$, since $E[NS|N]$ is the random variable whose expectation we take to invoke the law of iterated expectations.

Comment: @jesterII: had an extra bracket. Corrected